# How to use group by and min statment of linq for one array?

Tags: c#, linq

I need to get minimum of flights price in one day. `aFlightList` fill with all options of flights. In this array exist number flights for one day. I should get one flight in one day that this flight should has minimum price. I use linq such as this but in this section `Min(x => x.PriceView)` get error. How to fix this?

```
//AFlight is a class
AFlight[] aFlightList = { new AFlight() };
aFlightList = charterService
    .GetFlightList(chfs.DepCityId, true, chfs.ArrCityId, true, 
        chfs.Fromdate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"),
        chfs.Fromdate.AddDays(chfs.DateRange - 1).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"), 
        authentication);

aFlightList = (AFlight[])aFlightList
    .GroupBy(x => x.FlightDate)
    .Min(x => x.PriceView);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IGrouping` implements `IEnumerable`. Thus, you could get each individual item in the `IGrouping` and then get its `PriceView` and look for the minimum like this:

```
AFlight[] aFlightList =  { new AFlight() };
aFlightList = charterService.GetFlightList(chfs.DepCityId, true, chfs.ArrCityId, true, chfs.Fromdate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"), chfs.Fromdate.AddDays(chfs.DateRange - 1).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"), authentication);
aFlightList = aFlightList
    .GroupBy(x => x.FlightDate);
    .Select(g => g.OrderBy(x => x.PriceView).First())
    .ToArray();
```

The key is to get group's `IEnumerable` and ordering by `PriceView` to get the `First` (minimum)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the overload of GroupBy that takes a resultselector to do all of that at once, instead of only passing 1 lambda to select the key, pass a second one to select your result set :

```
var res = aFlightList
     .GroupBy(item => 
              // State that you want to group by date
              item.FlightDate, 
              // Will be called for each pair, you don't use the key as it's already part of the original object you will return, here for each group you'll only return a single item, the lowest priced one and will end up with an IEnumerable containing the cheapest one of each group
              (key, pairs) => pairs
                    .OrderBy(p => p.PriceView)
                    .First());
```

This overload of groupby returns a flat IEnumerable so you don't even end up with IGroupings with a single item in collection but with flat objects.